# ios app saving data with nsuserdefaults persistent?

Tags: ios, persistent, userinfo

I'm writing my first iOS app.  I need to take the user's ship to/delivery addresses and phone number.

1. Is it safe to use NSUserDefaults?

   I'm trying to keep this simple as I only need to save very basic data like name, delivery address, phone number.

   ```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"customerCity"]
   ```
2. Is this persistent across version upgrades?
3. Would the App Store reject the app for having user enter the delivery address and phone number?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, safe to do from a data persistence standpoint. Unencrypted personal info written to disk may be a separate security concern though...
2. As long as you don't change your code to overwrite that value, and the user hasn't deleted your app (and all of the data with it) then yes, NSUserDefaults persist when users upgrade versions.
3. Extremely unlikely that this would cause a rejection. They really aren't looking at that sort of a thing.

Comment: Thanks ryan. I'll think about encrypting.